# OpenAI api for creating wordpress posts - wp_insert_post create post three times instead of once

Tags: wp-insert-post

I have a custom PHP script which should get response from OpenAI API and build HTML article content from it and then push it to WP through `wp_insert_post()` function.
When I do `echo` for the article it goes well but if I try wp_insert_post then every article will be created three times. But after consultation with my friend I still don't know why and I didn't find out any relevant answer.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
function sys_name2($string)
{
  $string = stripslashes($string);
  $origin = array(' – ', ' - ', 'ě', 'š', 'č', 'ř', 'ž', 'ý', 'á', 'í', 'é', 'ů', 'ú', 'ó', 'ď', 'ň', 'ť', 'Ě', 'Š', 'Č', 'Ř', 'Ž', 'Ý', 'Á', 'Í', 'É', 'Ů', 'Ú', 'Ó', 'Ď', 'Ň', 'Ť', '&nbsp;', ' ', '/', '�', ':', ')', '(');
  $new = array('-', '-', 'e', 's', 'c', 'r', 'z', 'y', 'a', 'i', 'e', 'u', 'u', 'o', 'd', 'n', 't', 'E', 'S', 'C', 'R', 'Z', 'Y', 'A', 'I', 'E', 'U', 'U', 'O', 'D', 'N', 'T', '-', '-', '-', '-', '', '', '');
  // $spec_chars=array('\'','\\',',','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','()');    

  $string = strtolower(str_replace($origin, $new, trim($string)));
  $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string);

  return $string;
}
require_once( '../../wp-load.php' );

$curl = curl_init();    // create cURL session

$API_KEY = "sk-xxxx"; 
$games = [
            "Monopoly",
            "Pexeso",
            "GTA 3",
            "Blackjack",
            ];
            
$url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$headers = array( // cUrl headers (-H)
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Authorization: Bearer $API_KEY"
);
foreach($games as $hra) {
    $hraslug = sys_name2($hra);
    $article_title = $hra." recenze, torrent, HW požadavky";
    $html_content = "V článku <strong>".$hra." recenze, torrent, HW požadavky</strong> se dozvíte:<ul><li><a href='#".$hraslug."-recenze'>".$hra." recenze</a></li><li><a href='#".$hraslug."-torrent'>".$hra." torrent</a></li><li><a href='#".$hraslug."-hw-pozadavky'>".$hra." HW požadavky</a></li></ul><h2 id='".$hraslug."-recenze'>".$hra." recenze</h2>";
    //echo $html_content;
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $prompt = 'Napiš mi recenzi na hru '.$hra.'.';
    $prompt_hw = "Vypiš mi HW požadavky ke hře '.$hra 've formátu raw html tabulky s border='1'.";

    $messages_review = array(
        array(
            "role" => "system",
            "content" => "Budu se tě ptát na recenze na různé hry, prosím vytvoř unikátní text recenze dané hry, můžeš použít inspiraci i z jiných webů. Při generování textů si hlídej skloňování, gramatiku a pravopis v českého jazyka."
            ),
        array(
            "role" => "user",
            "content" => $prompt
        )
    );

    $messages_hw = array(
        array(
            "role" => "system",
            "content" => "Budu se tě ptát na HW požadavky na různé hry, prosím vytvoř HTML tabulku s rámečkem (element table v tomto případě využívá atribut border s hodnotou 1), pokud nevíš HW požadavky k dané hře, najdi si hru na internetu a na různých stránkách jako například Steam můžeš HW požadavky k dané hře určitě najít."
            ),
        array(
            "role" => "user",
            "content" => $prompt_hw
        )
    );

    $review_data = array( // cUrl data
        "model" => "gpt-3.5-turbo", // choose your designated model
        "messages" => $messages_review, // choose your prompt (what you ask the AI)
        "temperature" => 0.5,   // temperature = creativity (higher value => greater creativity in your promts)
        "max_tokens" => 1024     // max amount of tokens to use per request
    );

    $hw_data = array( // cUrl data
        "model" => "gpt-3.5-turbo", // choose your designated model
        "messages" => $messages_hw, // choose your prompt (what you ask the AI)
        "temperature" => 0.5,   // temperature = creativity (higher value => greater creativity in your promts)
        "max_tokens" => 1024     // max amount of tokens to use per request
    );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($review_data));

    $review_response = curl_exec($curl);               // execute cURL
    $review_response = json_decode($review_response, true);   // extract json from response
    //var_dump($review_response);

    $generated_text = $review_response['choices'][0]['message']['content'];  // extract first response from json
    $html_content .= $generated_text;
    $html_content .= "<h2 id='".$hraslug."-torrent'>".$hra." torrent</h2>Pokud hledáte ".$hra." torrent, buďte obezřetní ohledně virů, ideálně vždy před spuštěním torrent nahrajte na stránku virustotal.com která obsahuje databázi <a href='https://gamesquad.cz/nejlepsi-antivirove-programy/'>nejlepších antivirových programů</a>, čímž můžete pak snadno zkontrolovat přítomnost virů v torrentu. Pro větší bezpečnost však doporučujeme si hru ".$hra." koupit, opravdu to stojí za to, a koupí podpoříte vývojáře i v tom, aby vytvořili třeba další hru nebo nový obsah. Konkrétní ".$hra." torrent Vám tedy bohužel nenabídneme.<h2 id='".$hraslug."-hw-pozadavky'>".$hra." HW požadavky</h2>";
    //echo $html_content;   // output response

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($hw_data));

    $hw_response = curl_exec($curl);               // execute cURL
    $hw_response = json_decode($hw_response, true);   // extract json from response
    //var_dump($hw_response);
    $generated_hw = $hw_response['choices'][0]['message']['content'];
    $html_content .= $generated_hw;
    
    $postData = array(
        'post_title' => $article_title,
        'post_status' => 'draft',
        'post_content' => $html_content,
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_type'         =>   'post',
        'post_category' => array(55)
    );

    wp_insert_post($postData);
}
curl_close($curl);      // close cURL session*/
```

Do you have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where does this code run? Are you requesting the file directly?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Hi, the code running in custom chatgpt folder in the /wp-content/ folder, so the way is /wp-content/chatgpt/chatgpt.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue of your articles being created three times seems to be a result of the wp_insert_post() function being called multiple times. This typically happens when the code containing wp_insert_post() is executed more than once. Let's analyze your code to identify potential causes and solutions.

Here's an example of how you might check for existing posts:

```
foreach ($games as $hra) {
    // ... [rest of your code] ...

    $existing_posts = get_posts(array(
        'title' => $article_title,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'draft',
        'numberposts' => 1
    ));

    if (count($existing_posts) == 0) {
        wp_insert_post($postData);
    } else {
        // Post already exists, handle this scenario
    }
}
```

This code snippet checks if there is already a draft post with the same title before inserting a new one. Adjust this logic based on your specific requirements, such as checking for published posts or using a different unique identifier.

**Loop Execution:** Your wp_insert_post() function is inside a foreach loop. Ensure that this loop only iterates once for each item in the $games array. If there's any chance that the loop is executing more times than expected, this could be creating multiple posts.

**Check for Existing Posts:** Before inserting a new post, check if the post already exists to avoid duplicates. You can do this by querying posts with the same title or a unique identifier.

**Code Execution Path:** Ensure that your script is not being included or required multiple times in your application. This could inadvertently cause the whole script to run multiple times.

**Error Handling:** Add error handling to check the response of wp_insert_post(). If it's failing for some reason, it might be retried unintentionally.

**External Triggers:** Make sure that your script is not being triggered multiple times from the outside, for example, by a cron job or an external application.

**WordPress Actions and Filters:** Sometimes, WordPress actions and filters can cause unexpected behavior. Ensure that there are no such hooks in your theme or plugins that might be affecting wp_insert_post().

**Debugging:** Add logging statements before and after wp_insert_post() to see how many times it's being called. This can give you insights into where the problem might be.

**CURL Calls:** You are making CURL calls in the loop, ensure these calls are not affecting the loop's logic or inadvertently causing the loop to reiterate.

To address these points, here's a suggested approach:

**Check for Duplicates:** Before inserting a new post, check if a post with the same title already exists. If it does, skip the wp_insert_post() call.

**Debugging:** Add logging or debugging statements to check how many times your loop is running and how many times wp_insert_post() is called.

**Code Review:** Review your entire codebase for any possible re-inclusions of this script or unexpected triggers.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, your answer helped me, that if solves everything! But I still can't understand why it solved this problem? Because if there is one foreach and this wp_insert_post is inside of it, why it gonna repeats three times?